# Super Basic Sanity Schema Import

Tags: import, schema, sanity

I need some help importing schemas from Visual Studio Code into the Sanity console. I'm importing everything as usual and when Content Studio is successfully compiled I'm still not seeing anything in the Studio

I see Empty Schema every single time. Anyone know how to fix this?

one example of a schema im trying to import

```
export default{
    name:'abouts',
    title:'Abouts',
    type: 'document',
    fields:[
        {
            name:'title',
            title:'Title',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'description',
            title:'Description',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'imgUrl',
            title:'ImgUrl',
            type: 'image',
            options: {
              hotspot: true,
            },
        },

    ]
}
```

all my types are document

here is the schema.js

```
// First, we must import the schema creator
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator'

// Then import schema types from any plugins that might expose them
import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type'
import testimonials from './testimonials'
import about from './about'

// Then we give our schema to the builder and provide the result to Sanity
export default createSchema({
  // We name our schema
  name: 'default',
  // Then proceed to concatenate our document type
  // to the ones provided by any plugins that are installed
  types: schemaTypes.concat([
    testimonials,
    about
  ]),
})
```

I know its super simple but I'm trying to really dig in and get a portfolio started. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is named `abouts`, but you import `about` in the `schema.js`-file. The names must match.

Answer (score 0):

as stated above, make sure the names are exact. also under
types: schemaTypes.concat([

make sure each type has a comma after EVERY one, or it wont render it.

hope this helps. 45 min of digging around and testing and this is what fixed it.

so it should look like this:
types: schemaTypes.concat([
about,
testimonials,
brands,
ect....